# How to change background color in paragraph depending on the values reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change background color with check if `{this.state.list[0].main.temp}` > 10 background color of this paragraph to be yellow ..

Code:

```
const getBackground = (temperature) => {
    if(temperature > 30) return "red"
    if(temperature > 20) return "orange"
    if(temperature > 10) return "yellow"
    return "transparent"
  }
  
  renderForecast1 = () => {
    if (this.state && this.state.list) {
      const list = this.state.list[0];
      return (
        <p style={{ backgroundColor: getBackground(list.main.temp) }}>
          Date: {list.dt_txt}h <br />
          Temperature: {list.main.temp} °C <br />
          Chance of precipitation: {list.pop} mm <br />
          Wind Speed: {Math.round(list.wind.speed, 1) * 3.6} km/h <br />
          Pressure: {list.main.pressure} hPa <br />
          Humidity: {list.main.humidity} %
        </p>
      );
    }
  };
```

I receive error:

```
 SyntaxError: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\weather\weather\src\App.js: Unexpected token (86:8)

  84 |   };
  85 |
> 86 |   const getBackground = (temperature) => {
     |         ^
  87 |     if(temperature > 30) return "red"
  88 |     if(temperature > 20) return "orange"
  89 |     if(temperature > 10) return "yellow"
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a variable instead of repeating `this.state.list[0]` all the time.

```js
  const getBackground = (temperature) => {
  if(temperature > 30) return "red"
  if(temperature > 20) return "orange"
  if(temperature > 10) return "yellow"
  return "transparent"
}

renderForecast1 = () => {
if (this.state && this.state.list){
const list = this.state.list[0]
  return (
  <p style={{backgroundColor: getBackground(list.main.temp)}}>
    Date: {list.dt_txt}h <br />
    Temperature: {list.main.temp} °C <br />
    Chance of precipitation: {list.pop} mm <br />
    Wind Speed: {Math.round(list.wind.speed,1) * 3.6} km/h <br />
    Pressure: {list.main.pressure} hPa <br />
    Humidity: {list.main.humidity} %
  </p>;
)
  }
}
```

Comment: I want if is > 10 to be yellow if is > 20 to be orange if is > 30 to be red, can I get example ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it suits you, please mark it as valid so other people can benefit from a resolved thread.

Comment: ./src/App.js
SyntaxError: /Users/pizhev/Projects/weather/src/App.js: Unexpected token (87:8)

  85 |   };
  86 |
> 87 |   const getBackground (temperature){
     |         ^
  88 |     if(temperature > 30) return "red"
  89 |     if(temperature > 20) return "orange"
  90 |     if(temperature > 10) return "yellow"

Comment: I have unexpected token in const GetBackground when I put above renderForecast1.. can you check, please

Comment: Hi, I've updated the answer, sorry, it was late yesterday when I answered, I forgot the = and => in the const declaration^^.

Comment: I receive the same error: SyntaxError: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\weather\weather\src\App.js: Unexpected token (89:8)

  87 |
  88 |
> 89 |   const getBackground = (temperature) => {
     |         ^
  90 |     if(temperature > 30) return "red"
  91 |     if(temperature > 20) return "orange"
  92 |     if(temperature > 10) return "yellow"

Comment: I try your way, but this error is still the same I put const getBackground above renderForecast1..

Comment: The function getBackground is correctly written. Maybe you use an older version of React. If so, I think you can't declare functions with const above render(). You must directly write getBackground = () => dostuff and then call it with this.getBackground(). If you use hooks, please write the complete component (minus all irrelevant or sensitive details of course).